# How can I dedicate space to a label inside my component?

Tags: css, reactjs, error-handling

I have a textfield component with a label for errormessages. Whenever a errormessage appears, it missplaces the field with the error.

Is there anyway to preallocate the space needed for the errormessages?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow, check out how to make a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which will help get responses to your question and it might be worth checking out [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) too! There's not enough information here for me to recreate your issue.

Comment: could you provide code and some image or make a codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your text label inside div with fixed height or width. Your space will always be there, and you show your text based on your error.

Comment: Thanks, my brain isnt working properly atm.